# Create a nested form update button in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.

I am trying to create a button that updates table columns when pressed. This update is part of a nested resource, and my goal is to update this from the "show.html.erb" page that is called from the CallsController, not the `Calls::Respondings` controller.

My button looks like:

```
<%= link_to "Responding", unit_responding_update_call_responding_path, method: :patch %>
```

I have two controllers right now.  The first controller is `CallsController` and my `show` action in this controller is:

```
    class CallsController < ApplicationController

      def show
        @call = Call.find(params[:id])
        ## Responding Nested
        @respondings = @call.respondings
        ## Ping Nested
        @pings = @call.pings
        ## Agency Nested
        @agencies = @call.agencies
        ## Incidents Nested
        @incidents = @call.incidents
        ## Complainants Nested
        @complainants = @call.complainants
      end

  #Custom Controller Calls
  def unit_responding_update
    @responding = Responding.find(params[:id])
    @responding.responding_tme = DateTime.now
    @responding.responding = "true"
    @responding.on_scene = "false"
    @responding.clear = "false" 
    @responding.save!
  end
    end
```

The second controller I have is the nested form controller: (Where the Original Create Action Comes From)

```
class Calls::RespondingsController < ApplicationController


end
```

My routes.rb looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :calls do
    resources :respondings, except: [:index], controller: 'calls/respondings'
       member do
      patch :unit_responding_update
    end
    resources :pings, except: [:index], controller: 'calls/pings'
    resources :agencies, except: [:index], controller: 'calls/agencies'
    resources :incidents, except: [:index], controller: 'calls/incidents'
    resources :complainants, except: [:index], controller: 'calls/complainants'
  end

end
```

`rake routes` output for controller def link:

```
unit_responding_update_call_responding PATCH  /calls/:call_id/respondings/:id/unit_responding_update(.:format)           calls/respondings#unit_responding_update
```

`rake routes` output for Calls/Respondings:

```
call_responding_pings POST   /calls/:call_id/respondings/:responding_id/pings(.:format)                 calls/pings#create
              new_call_responding_ping GET    /calls/:call_id/respondings/:responding_id/pings/new(.:format)             calls/pings#new
             edit_call_responding_ping GET    /calls/:call_id/respondings/:responding_id/pings/:id/edit(.:format)        calls/pings#edit
                  call_responding_ping GET    /calls/:call_id/respondings/:responding_id/pings/:id(.:format)             calls/pings#show
                                       PATCH  /calls/:call_id/respondings/:responding_id/pings/:id(.:format)             calls/pings#update
                                       PUT    /calls/:call_id/respondings/:responding_id/pings/:id(.:format)             calls/pings#update
                                       DELETE /calls/:call_id/respondings/:responding_id/pings/:id(.:format)             calls/pings#destroy
```

I have searched and tried to find ways to complete this but it seems there is nothing out there for this type of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not save the record, so nothing happens. Change the method to following:

```
  def unit_responding_update
    @responding = Responding.find(params[:id])
    @responding.responding_tme = DateTime.now
    @responding.responding = "true"
    @responding.on_scene = "false"
    @responding.clear = "false" 
    @responding.save!
  end
```

I also think, you should pass the `call` and `@responding` objects ids in the url:

```
<%= link_to "Responding", unit_responding_update_call_responding_path(call_id: @call.id, id: @respondings.first.id), method: :patch %>
```

---

Sidenote:

I also think, the code defined in the `unit_responding_update` action does not belong to controller. You should create the instance method in the `Responding` class with the updating code:

```
def unit_responding_update
  update!(
    responding_time: DateTime.now,
    responding: true,
    on_scene: false,
    clear: false
  )
end
```

and then, controller's action just call this instance method on the object.

Comment: Os so in the link where you have call_id: your_call_object.id, id: @responding... is the your_call_object referencing the code i place in the model class?

Comment: No, the thing with code in model is a refactoring suggestion, not obligatory. First try to make work what you have.

Comment: Btw the params in link are updated (according to routes you've shown)

Comment: I made an error when I added the member do originally ill edit the post.. my apologies.

Comment: So CallsController is the Parent, where the view i want the button to be is located, Calls::RespondingsController is where the nested resources form is generated from, the rake routes links are correct now my apologies.

Comment: And now i am getting this error when using the link undefined method `unit_responding_update_call_responding_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fcafbbbff08>:0x007fcafbbbf238>

Comment: https://github.com/swilson223/Pat_Pro_CAD_Bootstrap is my Git for this if that would help you any to see it in full context

Comment: Thanks for your help with setting up the link! my problem was in the routes file along, however your link was the proper way to set this up! ill award best answer!

Comment: @ShawnWilson no probs, glad you solved it. See how I defined the route and always follow this pattern (in `routes.rb`check what ids the url requires and pass it - you will never be wrong this way :))

Comment: yeah it was just sneaky.. lol.. because i was missing the second end it wasnt pulling the respondings id.. i must have changed it while hacking away.. once again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the Fix to this problem was soley in the routes file.. it turns out I was missing and end.. After changing my routes file to the following, it solved the initial problem altogether.

```
  resources :calls do
    resources :respondings, except: [:index], controller: 'calls/respondings' do
      member do
        patch :unit_responding_update
      end
    end
    resources :pings, except: [:index], controller: 'calls/pings'
    resources :agencies, except: [:index], controller: 'calls/agencies'
    resources :incidents, except: [:index], controller: 'calls/incidents'
    resources :complainants, except: [:index], controller: 'calls/complainants'
  end
end
```